# Details in class file

Tags: java, eclipse, class

When we compile java file we will get class file which contains byte code.
My question is

The class file generated is contains information about javafile?

Because in eclipse when we created one java file and adding one line itself class file is generated.When add more contents to that same java file,the class file size is not increasd.Actually in class file what we have?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

Comment: And http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/

Answer (score 2):

Your Eclipse is building automatically from the source code to the class file when you hit the save button (or hit ctrl-S).
If you save, you'll see the increase in your class file.

Answer (score 0):

Class file contains the bytecode. if you make changes to your source file, then you have to recompile the java code and another class file is created which replaces the previous class file. also the size is increased/decreased accordingly.
When you use eclipse and make changes in the source file, when you save the changes eclipse itself recompile the java file and replaces the previous class file with increased size.